# How to get in single json column from comma seperated string in azure databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Have data as below

[image]

Need to get it in output as

[image]

Slabenddays and optimal slab days are configurable 3 or 5 0r more..

Above req can achive using spark sql but need to achieve this using pyspark.

Comment: Here question is how can we achieve dynamically  adding into a single column from given string. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Created functions as below

```
def func(slab_end_days,optimal_slab_rates):

l = []
start_index = 1
slab_end_days_list = slab_end_days.split(",")
optimal_slab_rates_list = optimal_slab_rates.split(",")
for i in range(len(slab_end_days_list)):
    
    o = {}
    #print("i:",i)
    if i == 0:
        
        o['start_day'] = start_index
        o['end_day'] = slab_end_days_list[0]
        o["rate"] = optimal_slab_rates_list[0]
    else:
        o['start_day'] = int(slab_end_days_list[i-1])+1
        o['end_day'] = slab_end_days_list[i]
        o["rate"] = optimal_slab_rates_list[i]
  #print(o)
    l.append(o)
    
return(l)
```

Create UDF as below

```
func_udf = udf(lambda col1,col2: func(col1,col2), ArrayType(StructType([StructField('start_day', StringType(), nullable=False),StructField('end_day', StringType(),nullable=False),StructField('rate',StringType(),nullable=False)])))
```

Call this in dataframe

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('output',func_udf(col("slab_end_days_list"), col("optimal_slab_rates_list")))
```

Output as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwSTV.png)